# Want a simple grid layout algorithm for as3

Tags: actionscript-3, grid-layout

Can anyone please help me with a simple grid making algorithm with following requirements :

- i have rectangle boxes of **variable width** but same height
- i want to form a grid of 2 rows with n number of boxes
- the boxes should be spaced at a distance of 10 px from each other both horizontally and vertically

thanks :)

Edit : wow... after reading the first response... i guess i'll try to be a whole lot more specific about my posts.

- i dont want the whole code... i just need a 2-3 line algorithm that's it.

**what i have tried is this** :

boxList is an array having all the boxes...

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < boxList.length; i++)
{
    var b:Box = new Box(boxList[i]);
    this.addChild(b);

    b.y = 5 + (i % 2) * (b.height + 10);
    b.x = 10 + int(i / 2) * (b.width + 5);
}
```

BUT this one works only if the width of the boxes are same... in my case the width is different... so how to do that ????

Comment: @Panzercrisis : i have edited my question and have added my specific problem too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend some of the other details about how you would want this done.  For instance, do you want both rows to be as close to the same width as possible?  Do you want the same number of boxes on each row, plus possibly one extra on one of the rows when there's an odd number?  Etc.

Going by your code, it looks like you are trying to get an even number of boxes on each row.  The important thing, if you tile from left to right, would be to always take the last box you just put down on that row, add its x property and width property together (giving you the position of its right edge), and then just add 10 to that.

So working from your original code, maybe something like this will work:

```
var bLast1:Box; // added
var bLast2:Box; // added

for (var i:int = 0; i < boxList.length; i++)
{
    var b:Box = new Box(boxList[i]);
    this.addChild(b);

    b.y = 5 + (i % 2) * (b.height + 10);
    if (i % 2 == 0) // is this the first row?
    {
        b.x = bLast1 ? bLast1.x + bLast1.width + 10 : 10;
        bLast1 = b;
    }
    else
    {
        b.x = bLast2 ? bLast2.x + bLast2.width + 10 : 10;
        bLast2 = b;
    }
}
```

Again, you may have to make some more decisions about exactly how you want the tiling to be done.

Answer (score 1):

You know the width of the stage, and the width of each box being added.

Simple have a variable keeping track of the current horizontal limit.

ie, some pseudocode:

```
lastX=0
for(box in boxes)
    if(lastX + box[i].width > width)
        lastX = box[i].width
        add box to next row, with x = 0
    else
        add box at lastX
        lastX += box[i].width
```